# Theorem 13.4 Apostol, pg 285 - unnecessary condition?

Tags: asymptotics, proof-explanation, analytic-number-theory

In [Theorem 13.4](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=3yoBCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA285&lpg=PA285&dq=13.4%20Apostol%20number%20theory&source=bl&ots=Fqb_TCGUfL&sig=ZU_yodn1x8ZV_7jsoVmbPqgHFZo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjz_dXSn6zVAhUkOsAKHZ3SA2UQ6AEIMDAC#v=onepage&q=13.4%20Apostol%20number%20theory&f=false):

[image]

**Why do we need $\sigma \ge \frac{1}{2}$?** The representation for $\zeta(s)$ holds for all $\sigma > 0$ in (17) (page 284) and the proof does not utilize $\sigma \ge \frac{1}{2}.$

---

EDIT: Actually, I believe it is used in the line,
$$ \frac{2t}{\sigma N^{\sigma}} = O( \frac{1}{N} ). $$

Comment: Don't ask about every line of your book, read the next pages, ask about things you really need. $|\zeta(s)| = \mathcal{O}(\log t)$ is more or less trivial, what we really care about is $|\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}| = \mathcal{O}(\log^k t),|\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}| = \mathcal{O}(\log^k t)$ in the zero-free region, for proving the prime number theorem..

Comment: You are right. I do get more understanding after reading the next pages. Thanks.